# AX 2012 SSRS Report visibility issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In my report, the data is being inserted into my temporary table. The problem is the data does not show on the report. I have removed all hidden and visibility expressions as well.

It's the ProjInvoiceReport. I added a second data set which needs to insert multiple values for one field. The data is being inserted into the table, but when I put the field in a table control (correct data set) on the report...nothing appears!

In the ProjInvoiceDP class I added a get method

```
[
    SRSReportDataSetAttribute(tableStr(ProjInvoiceServiceOrderTmp))
]
public ProjInvoiceServiceOrderTmp getProjInvoiceServiceOrderTmp()
{
    select * from projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp;
    return projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp;
}
```

and an initTempTable method

```
    public void initTempTableFromSMAServiceOrder(ProjTable  _projTable, ProjInvoiceId 
    _projInvoiceId)
    {
    SMAServiceOrderLine serviceOrderLine;
    ProjEmplTrans       projEmplTrans;
    ProjItemTrans       projItemTrans;

    iProjInvoiceId = _projInvoiceId;

ttsBegin;
delete_from projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp where projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ProjInvoiceId ==
iProjInvoiceId;
ttsCommit;

while select serviceOrderLine
    join projEmplTrans
    where serviceOrderLine.ProjTransId == projEmplTrans.TransId
        && serviceOrderLine.ProjId  ==  _projTable.ProjId
{
    if(projEmplTrans.invoiceId() == iProjInvoiceId)
    {
        projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.clear();
        projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ServiceOrderId       = serviceOrderLine.ServiceOrderId;
      //  projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ShowFieldTicketInfo  = #True;
        projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ProjInvoiceId = iProjInvoiceId;
        projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.insert();
    }
}

while select serviceOrderLine
    join projItemTrans
    where serviceOrderLine.ProjTransId == projItemTrans.ProjTransId
        && serviceOrderLine.ProjId  ==  _projTable.ProjId
{
    if(projItemTrans.invoiceId() == iProjInvoiceId)
        {
            projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.clear();
            projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ServiceOrderId       = serviceOrderLine.ServiceOrderId;
          //  projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ShowFieldTicketInfo  = #True;
            projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.ProjInvoiceId = iProjInvoiceId;
            projInvoiceServiceOrderTmp.insert();
        }
    }

}
```

The initTempTable method is called in the insertIntoProjInvoiceTmp at the very end before projInvoiceTmp.insert(). One person that has previously worked on this report called their initTempTableFromProjTable in the same area.

The insertIntoProjInvoiceTmp is called within the fetch method. The processReport calls the fetch method.

Any idea on what the issue is?

Comment: It's the ProjInvoiceReport. I added a second data set which needs to insert multiple values for one field. The data is being inserted into the table, but when I put the field in a table control (correct data set) on the report...nothing appears!

Comment: When you say second dataset, how is this dataset being selected? AX has strange integration with SSRS. I believe it does more than just a simple select *, because I have browsed the tmp tables it selects from and there are sometimes more data than just what is showing on the report. Sometimes it still includes data from the previous time I ran the report.

Comment: Strange. In the ProjInvoiceDP I added a get method like Jan has provided below. I wrote an initTempTableFrom* method which is called at the end--right before projInvoiceTmp.insert()-- in the insertIntoProjInvoiceTmp. In Visual Studios, I created a new dataset which allowed me to select all fields from the new "temp" table. I will edit my post with code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the table TempDB temporary?

Did you a proper change of the `ProjInvoiceDP` class, making a new method?

```
[SRSReportDataSetAttribute(tableStr(MyTmp))]
public MyTmp getMyTmp()
{
    select myTmp;
    return myTmp;    
}
```

Comment: Yes--also the strange thing is the ProjInvoiceTmp table is a regular table. Visual studios would not allow me to make a TempDB table for the second dataset either.

Since it's forced to be a regular table, I can see the data is inserted when the report runs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a well known issue:

Some fields are just not shown if client display settings are not set to 100%.

See [this Microsoft technote](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg231521.aspx)

Try to alter this - it worked instantly for me